# Analog to the identity theorem for holomorphic functions for functions of two complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that is holomorphic and vanishes on a non empty bounded open set $S$. If $f$ were a function from $\mathbb{C}$, by the identity theorem, $f$ would be uniquely determined to be the zero function. Does a similar theorem hold when the domain is $\mathbb{C}^2$? If not, how can the vector space of all functions vanishing on $S$ be categorized or expressed? For example, I would be interested in listing them all if possible, or knowing the dimension of the vector space of all such functions.

Comment: I suppose you want to assume $S$ is nonempty, rather than that $S$ is bounded.

Comment: @EricWofsey, thanks, I fixed the question

Comment: This is true in $n$ variables for arbitrary domains and the proof is the same as in the 1-dimensional case. See for example Theorem 1.2.6 from [here](https://www.jirka.org/scv/scv.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can deduce this from the single-variable case.  Pick a point $p\in S$, so $f$ vanishes on a neighborhood of $p$.  Now for any other $q\in\mathbb{C}^2$, consider the function $g(z)=f(zq+(1-z)p)$.  This is a holomorphic function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, and is basically the restriction of $f$ to the (complex) line between $p$ and $q$.  Since $f$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $p$, $g$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $0$, so $g=0$.  In particular, $g(1)=0$ so $f(q)=0$.  Since $q$ was arbitrary, $f=0$.