# identity principle for several complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

In one dimensional case, we have the identity principle that if holomorphic function vanish on an open subset, it will vanish identically, this also holds for serval complex variable by [restricting the function on the line.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981756/360262)

We also have if for a one dimensional holomorphic function that has zero as limit point, it will vanish identically, I guess I must misinterpret that this version also holds for serveral complex variable.

Since by contradiction if for a $f(z_1,z_2)$ that has isolated zero at origin, then it will violate the Rouché's theorem as we perturb $z_1$ it should have same number of zeros as before in a small neiborhood.

---

therefore for several complex variables the zeros can be a limit point (and it must be a limit point it's the vanishing locus) correct?

Comment: generally speaking, the zeroes of holomorphic functions in $n$ variables are hypersurfaces

Comment: yeah , thank you i have misinterpreted this point for a long time. I mean the identity principle

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the case that $wz$,  the number of zeros is not preserve when perturb in direction $z_1$